# How to import fields with readonly attr in Odoo14?

Tags: python, odoo, readonly, enterprise, odoo-14

I would like to import fields with readonly attr from web, specifically field and values from 'mail.tracking.value' model.

I have tried to change fields by inheriting, but it haven't worked as spected:

```
from datetime import datetime

from odoo import api, fields, models


class MailTracking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.tracking.value'

    field = fields.Many2one(readonly=False)
    field_desc = fields.Char('Field Description', required=True, readonly=False)
    field_type = fields.Char('Field Type', readonly=False)

    old_value_integer = fields.Integer('Old Value Integer', readonly=False)
    old_value_float = fields.Float('Old Value Float', readonly=False)
    old_value_monetary = fields.Float('Old Value Monetary', readonly=False)
    ...
```

Anyone has a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sometimes the fields are set to be readonly in the xml side. You should check it too.

Comment: I understand that, in this case those fields are made readonly by field definition through py code, if the case was xml side, those could be importable.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can try add this `force_save="1"`attribute on xml field, it used to force save when field is readonly.